# XML reading and encoding problems

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I'm trying to use an XMLDocument to read an XML file. Though, I get some issues with encoding. I read the XML Document like this :

```
Dim xmldoc As New XmlDataDocument()
Dim xmlnode As XmlNodeList
Dim i As Integer
Dim fs As New FileStream(tbFileLocation.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
xmldoc.Load(fs)
xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Message")
For i = 0 To xmlnode.Count - 1
    Dim SMSToAdd As New SMS()
    For Each Child As XmlElement In xmlnode(i).ChildNodes
        Dim Name As String = Child.Name.ToString()
        If Name = "Body" Then
            ContenuDuMessage = Child.InnerText
        End If
    Next
    'Other things
 Next
```

The problem is that my XML document contains emojis. When I read the file, put the nodes (with emojis) in variables and then write them to another file, everything works as expected. Though, if I use the following code :

```
    Dim Temp As Char() = Content.ToCharArray()
    Dim Returned As String = ""
    For Each Character In Temp
        Dim Result As Tuple(Of Boolean, Tuple(Of String, String)) = CharToSurrogates(Character.ToString())
        If Result.Item1 Then
            Returned &= "&#" & ConvertHexToDec(Result.Item2.Item1) & "; &#" & ConvertHexToDec(Result.Item2.Item2) & ";"
        Else
            Returned &= Character
        End If
    Next
    Return Returned
```

Content is a node value, so it may contain emojis. The goal here is to transform the emoji into XML entities in order to be able to read it in an Android application that needs the emojis to be converted. The CharToSurrogates method basically just gets the surrogates associated with a character returning a Tuple(Of Boolean, Tuple(Of String, String)) describing whether or not the character is an emoji and then the two surrogates associated.

Though, whenever I use my code, the emojis don't appear like emojis but like little squares, thus causing the thing to never work:

[image: Square]

How can I fix this ?

PS : CharToSurrogates method can be found here: http://pastebin.com/LiBB1q2p

Comment: Are you sure your IDE can show emojis? That square is shown usually when the font doesn't include that character. Have you checked the actual UNICODE value of the character? Also why use `ToString()` and compare strings when you can just compare the character?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but I used XmlDocument heavily in a recent project and then later someone suggested I should use XDocument (seems to have many more LINQ-like and modern features).  I was way too far down the rabbit hole.  As for the emoji, like @Sami suggested, getting the unicode value and perhaps storing & printing that may work better

Comment: Well I'm not sure it can display the emojis... Though, if I use two different emojis and call the charToSurrogates method on both, I get twice the same returned value, which is (False, ("FFFD", "")). The ToString thing was just to test actually. What do you mean by the unicode value?

Comment: If I debug.print the character, it does the same. If I get the unicode value using [this](http://pastebin.com/56Tz0Z1G) I get D83D, so it... kind of works? But I need both the first surrogate D83D and the second one which I Don't know how to get.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE can't (at least mine can't) display the emoji in the debugger.  I wrote this test to see how it looks when saved.

```
    Dim someXML As XElement

    someXML = <root>
                  <emoji></emoji>
              </root>
    '
    Dim emoji As String = ""
    someXML.<emoji>.Value = emoji
    someXML.Save("C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Desktop\emoji.xml")
```

When I looked at the file (double clicked the file name) the emoji displayed properly.

I used the items listed in the 'Browser' column from here, http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html and they seemed to work, at least the ones I tried.

```
    Dim emoji As String = ""
```